# Question about tensile test of model from research paper

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, 3d-printing, research, porous-medium

In this [paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/jbm.a.36289) they made a tensile force test on their four different models with four different pore size structure to show that pore size is not affecting on the tensile force. But it seems that they used only 1 layer thick specimen of the model, which is strange for me. Is this test done correctly? Can we conclude by doing this test, saying that pore size don't affect on the tensile force parameter like the author did?

Comment: Have you asked the authors?

Comment: You should make the question self-contained, so that peopled don't need to visit another site to read about all the relevant information. More so, its bad practice (at least if you want to get an answer) to point to a paywalled link.